# Sending newsletters of restricted content

Tags: emails

We have a single Drupal site, which contains our public facing website, as well as our internal Intranet.

All of the Intranet content uses content types which are restricted to certain user roles.

Within the Intranet section, is a content type named "Intranet News Item", which is pretty much as it says on the tin! We would like to send a weekly email which contains a list of all the new news items.

I have created a view which does this, but when I try to use SimpleNews (with the Insert Views module), it sends blank. I have tried sending with a different view (of publically viewable content), which works, therefore suggesting that the reason the email is received blank is that the content is restricted by permission.

Is there any way to overcome this that you can think of?

Comment: I'm happy to consider alternatives to SimpleNews if that would make it any easier!!